# Calling julia functions with keyword arguments using macro

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a macro which calls functions with keyword arguments (for using in JuMP NLexpressions and mappings. This functions are just functions for accessing a database. So they do not represent a mathematical operation).

Minimal example:

```
function foo1(; int::a=1)
    a
end

function foo2(; int::a=1, int::b=2)
    b
end

macro callfunc(f, keywordargs)
    #function should be called here using symbol
    #return values of f should be returned by macro callfunc
    ex= :($(that)(;$(keywordargs)...)) #this syntax is not correct for sure
    return eval(ex) 
end

@callfunc(foo1, (a=1))
#should return 1

@callfunc(foo2, (a=1, b=2))
#should return 2
```

I hope you get my idea, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear to me why you need a macro for this, but anyway.

1. The Julia syntax for

   ```
   function foo1(; int::a=1)
       a
   end
   ```

   is

   ```
   function foo1(; a::Int=1)
       a
   end
   ```
2. Don't call `eval` from a macro, macros takes an expression as input and should return an expression.
3. User input needs to be `esc`aped, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Hygiene-1

Here is a prototype implementation:

```
macro callfunc(f, kwargs...)
    x = [esc(a) for a in kwargs]
    return :($(f)(; $(x...)))
end
```

with example usage:

```
julia> foo1(; a::Int = 1) = a;

julia> foo2(; a::Int = 1, b::Int = 2) = b;

julia> @callfunc foo1 a = 5
5

julia> @callfunc foo2 a = 5 b = 6
6
```

Comment: this works perfectly with Julia 1.0. But Im facing compatibility problems with Julia 0.6.4. What would it look like in Julia 0.6x?

Answer (score 0):

For lower Julia versions it can be solved like:

```
macro NL(f, kwargs...)
    #julia 1.0 code:
    # x = [esc(a) for a in kwargs]
    # return :($(f)(; $(x...)))

    #for julia 0.6.x this needs to be a dict (symbol => value)
    x_dict = Dict(a.args[1] => a.args[2] for a in kwargs)
    #todo: add escaping!
    return :($(f)(; $(x_dict...)))
end
```

Note: So far I wasn't able to add the escaping...